# TextBox Content as a name for Textfile

Tags: c#

I'm still a newbie for C#. **I just want to know if it's possible that an input from textbox will be the name of your textfile?**

Example: **I input test in textbox, then the the name of my textfile or my textfile would be test.txt**

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
string filename = textBox1.Text;

            string path = Path.Combine(@"E:\Majel\Tic Tac Toe\TextFiles", filename+".txt");
```

I really need your help. How to this? 
Thank you

Comment: `File.Move` is that you need.

Comment: Sir can you provide example?

Comment: `File.Move("C:\Path\textfile", Path.Combine("C:\Path\", textBox1.Text);`

Comment: `string path = Path.Combine(@"E:\Majel\Tic Tac Toe\TextFiles\", filename + ".txt");`

Comment: @jayvee, sir that's how I code it, but still it doesn't work

Comment: @pwas, sir what I want to happen is that, the text from the textbox will be the the textfile name.

Comment: Can you please what you mean by not working? And check if the folder exists or not where you are trying to access the file

Comment: My apologize, I want to create a textfile and named it from the text inputed by the user. The code above doesn't work, it gave me nothing.

Comment: doesn't work? post the error so we can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is on how you create text file using FileInfo

```
string filename = textBox1.Text;
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"E:\Majel\Tic Tac Toe\TextFiles\", filename + ".txt");
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
file.Create();
```

Comment: sir, it's working, however, the textfile does not have a name.

Comment: What to do with this sir?

Comment: you should enter any alphanumeric on your textBox1 then execute that code

Answer (score 1):

You only generated the file path with your code, but did not create any file.
Try this:

```
string mypath = Path.Combine(@"E:\Majel\Tic Tac Toe\TextFiles\", filename+".txt");
System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(mypath);
// make sure your folder path is valid
```

Comment: Sir,can you provide the whole code on how to do that? I tried this **string filename = textBox1.Text + ".txt";
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"E:\Majel\Tic Tac Toe\TextFiles\", filename);
            System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);** but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files

Answer (score 0):

I you want litle change

```
string filename=txtfilename.text;
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"E:\Majel\Tic Tac Toe\TextFiles\", filename + ".txt");
File.Create(path);
```

you try also

```
     string filename = textBox1.text;
     string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"E:\", filename + ".txt");
     System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
     file.Create();
      if (File.Exists(path))
          {
           TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
           tw.WriteLine("The next line!");
           tw.Close(); 
         }
     filename =string.Empty;
     textBox1.text=string.Empty;
```

try this

```
        string filename = txtfilename.text;
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"D:\", filename + ".txt");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter(fs);
        str.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        str.Write("mytext.txt.........................");
        str.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " " +
                      DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        string addtext = "this line is added" + Environment.NewLine;
        str.Flush();
        str.Close();
        fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
string filename = textBox1.Text.Trim() + ".txt";
string path = Path.Combine(@"E:\Majel\Tic Tac Toe\TextFiles\", filename);
```

Comment: Sir, It's running but it doesn't produce  textfile.