# How to Write file in C#?

Tags: c#, file

```
 string attachment = "attachment; filename=Myfile.csv";
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");

// My logic goes here to write file.

// Now I want to copy above file to another file.

 string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/ExportedFiles/") +"Newfile.csv";
 var ExcelFile = File.Create(filepath);
 ExcelFile.Close();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(filepath);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

The above code is not working, please suggest me. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to read from and write to files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files)

Comment: Please define "not working" - compile error, runtime error, unexpected output? Plus any details about that error.

Comment: Not getting any error. But its not writing to Newfile.csv

Comment: You *should* be getting an error, you sure you're not swallowing the exception somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a virtual directory on your IIS and share that virtual directory directory. Your csv should reside in your virtual directory shared location. here is referenced article: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/502741/A-solution-to-problem-Response-TransmitFile

Answer (score 0):

use code bellow rather than:  var ExcelFile = File.Create(filepath);
WriteAllLines instruction in C# use to create file or change content file

```
File.WriteAllLines(filepath, data);
```

Comment: Please add some description rather than just posting the answer, it will help others to avoid the problems in the future.