# Unity - how to save record? with playerpref

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can anyone explain to me, how to save "score" with PlayerPrefs and display it on the screen?

```
public class record : MonoBehaviour{

private Text counterText;
public float score;

void Start()
{
    counterText = GetComponent<Text>() as Text;

}

void Update()
{
    score += Time.deltaTime;
    counterText.text = "Score: " + score.ToString("00");
}}
```

Comment: This is not [tag:c]!

Comment: this is `C++` code, not `C` code, they are two different languages.  Please replace the `c` tag with `c++`,

Comment: @user3629249 Nope, not C++ either. Unity uses C#.

Comment: ... and I suspect it isn't about [tag:unity] but [tag:unity3d]

Comment: Read the documentation. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html and http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetInt.html is all you need. There are enough code examples out there if you are willing to search.

Comment: You dont need to cast `GetComponent<Text>()` with as `Text`, becouse GetComponent returns directly `Text` type. It is Generic method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add 2 methods to your class

```
void SaveScore()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("score", score);
}

void LoadScore()
{
    PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score");
}
```

More informations about PlayerPrefs here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

PlayerPrefs are stored in the system registry. It's not a good idea to use them to save the score, [prefer a simple text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files) with encryption: ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp), [Unity Forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/secured-playerprefs-complete-code.256878/))

Comment: "prefer a simple text file" i think it isn`t good idea, bcs player will be able to edit it :/

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, Loper, you are right.
But the system regitry is also editable with the regedit command.
Altough you can easily encrypt the file/string:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp | http://tekeye.biz/2015/encrypt-decrypt-c-sharp-string

Answer (score 1):

`PlayerPrefs` utility is use to store data permanently till the app installed on device. And types supported to store is limited, such as `float`, `int`, `string`. You can further use it, derive new methods using `int` and `string`, its up to you.

`PlayerPrefs` uses `Key-Value` structure, that means it will store a value (int, float, string) against a `string` key. For example I'd save high score against the key `"highscore"`, and by the same `string` key I'd get back the stored value.

Now, to save score you can use

```
// To set high score
int scoreToSet = 140;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", scoreToSet);

// To get high score
int scoreToGet = 0;
scoreToGet = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore");
```

where `"highscore"` is the `string` key. Key must match in order to get and set values.