# save data from textboxes into a class c#

Tags: c#

I have to write a program for school.

In this program I have a couple of textboxes, the data from the textboxes has to be saved but not in a file. The form looks like this:

[image]

When the Save button is pressed, it has to save the data that is entered in the textboxes.

My second question is: I have the "<" and ">" buttons with these I have to make that they can change between the saved data. I would make it with a list but my knowledge is too little for it.

Thanks for every answer I get.

(Sorry for my bad English, I am learning the language)

Comment: You need a Class Person and a List<Person> so you can add more than one person.  The < and > would enumerate through the List<Person>.

Comment: Thanks but how do i save them into the class?

Comment: Person person = new Person(); person.Name = Name.Text; person.Ort = Ort.Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Data must be saved somewhere physically, like a file or DB.
Class is just a structural concept NO data is stored there.
So
Define a class say Person and with every save button clicked collect data from your form to Person object pass it to your (data storage) like a file.

Comment: Can you make an example ? and thanks for the explanation.

Comment: `Class Person{
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public int Age{get;set;}
 public string Address{get;set;}
}`

When ButtonSave clicked
`Person p1 = new Person{
 Name = textBox1.Text;
 Age = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
 Address = textBox3.Text;
}`


Then Write your object to your file
see these links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: Thank you sooo much, you helped me alot.