# Create and download text file

Tags: .net, file, api

I need to implement download button in my View and when user click i need to read some records from database create a file and download.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
stream.Position = 0;

var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
return response;
```

This is the code that I have for now, but I don't know how to write some data to it and how to convert to txt file.

Do i need to create it before and store on the server and here just to read it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your txt file before return from api. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files) how to create a txt file.

This is your method which is return the stream.

```
var path = @"C:\YourFile.txt";
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(path);   
result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
return result;
```