# Sending HTML Email - How to attach the .html file to the email?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following method for sending a simple email:

```
private void WelcomeMail(string recipient)
{
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("MyEmail", recipient);
    StringBuilder sbEmailBody = new StringBuilder();

    sbEmailBody.Append("How can I attach .html file here instead of writing the whole code");

    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mailMessage.Body = sbEmailBody.ToString();
    mailMessage.Subject = "Welcome to domain.com";
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
    {
        UserName = "MyEmail",
        Password = "MyPassword"
    };
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

What should I remove/change/add to send an HTML formatted email?

The HTML file is called responsivemail.html and contains more than 100+ lines of html code (that's the problem).

Comment: What HTML are you wanting to append?  You're doing everything correctly, you just lack the HTML.  Do you want the HTML as an *attachment*, or in the *body*?

Comment: Looks like you've already got it? You just need to actually put HTML tags in the strings you add to `sbEmailBody`. So I'm not really sure what you're asking for? Anways, if you're going to be doing HTML email, you should probably look into [Postal](https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal).

Comment: I took a HTML Email from a website (it's an html file with all the <html> <head> <body> etc tags). I asked on how can I attach that .html file instead of copy paste-ing the whole code (which is quite a lot) in the append area

Comment: You haven't shown that in your question. Where's the variable containing the HTML file?

Comment: @mason The problem is that the HTML code is way too long, so is there a way like StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate.html")) or something?

Comment: What about just `var html = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate.html"))`?

Comment: @mason You mean string html right? And where should I put it? sbEmailBody.Append("html"); ?

Comment: You can just assign it directly to the body unless you have more content to add. No need for the builder. It's just a simple string.

Comment: @mason Aha, I see. Thanks for the tip! I'll try it out

Comment: @Amy Sorry - Missed your comment, but I guess you understand the problem from above comments. I tried the string html = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/EN/EmailTemplate.html")); and then mailMessage.Body = html.ToString(); But it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Yes.  FYI, you can format small snippets of code in comments using backticks, `\`like so\``

Comment: If `html` is already a string, then there's no need to then call `.ToString()` on it. And you'll need to describe what "doesn't work". Do you get an error? What is the result? Does `html` contain your HTML content when you view it in the debugger?

Comment: @mason All fine now! I had a logical error from something else, but that method of yours works perfectly. One thing I noticed is that the images won't appear on the email because of SSL certificate which I don't have :p Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: You could embed the images directly in the email, or host them on a website yourself and change the URLs within the email to point to them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to read from and write to files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the HTML file in your site root in a file called emailtemplate.html, you can simply read the HTML into memory and assign it to the body of the email.

```
mailMessage.Body = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/emailtemplate.html"));
```

I don't recommend this, but you could also embed the HTML into your code directly. Since the HTML spans multiple lines, we'll need to use a string literal (`@"this is a string literal"`). The HTML likely has double quotes in it. You'd need to escape them by doubling your double quotes.

```
mailMessage.Body = @"
  <h1>This is HTML in an email!</h1>
  <a href=""http://google.com\"">This is a test link.</a>
";
```

Long term, if you're going to be sending emails with HTML and you need to inject values into them, I suggest you look into [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) or other libraries. Postal can even make it easy to [embed images](http://aboutcode.net/postal/embedding-images.html).