# Azure Chatbot - sending email

Tags: azure, email, bots, botframework, chatbot

I've digitize a word document form by creating a chatbot on Azure Bot framework. I'm stuck now.

How do I get it to package all the responses from the user into a document and send the document to my email?

Comment: A Bot Framework bot is just a web API application.  You would write to a file and send an email the same way you would in any similar application.

Comment: Got it, do you have some code reference i can use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp are good places to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using web as an integration channel then you should be able to do something like this. I have directly taken everything present in `conversation-area` & sent it as html file in mail. If you're willing to send a file, you should write it in file & email it.

```
var useremail = JSON.stringify(response.result.parameters.email[0]);
var obj = document.getElementById("conversation-area").innerHTML;
var str = "<html><head></head><body>";
str += obj + "</body></html>";
email(useremail, str);
```