# How can I get button's background color and send it to other form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a project with 2 forms, the first form is empty. The second form has 5 buttons.

When I press a button, it opens a color dialog. I'm choosing a color, and button's background color is changing. For example, if `button1`'s background color id is `Green`, `form1`'s background color should be green. Not instant but when I press the **Save** button. I need to get button's background color into a variable. How can I do this?

```
private void btnKAMU_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
    btnKAMU.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
}
```

Comment: I think is better open the second form passing a reference to the first form than storing the new backgroud color in a variable. So you can simply use this reference to set new color when the user clicks save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a reference of `Form1` to `Form2` setting `Form2` [`Owner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx), with a custom Property or using `Form2` constructor.

**When, in `Form1`, you create an instance of `Form2`:**

*Using then Owner property*:
(`Form2` `Owner` is set when you instantiate a Form this way:
`form2.Show(this);`. The `this` reference is `Form2` [Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) - `Form1` here).

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show(this);
//form2.ShowDialog(this);
```

In `Form2`, set the `Owner` `BackColor` property:

```
private void btnSAVE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Owner.BackColor = btnKAMU.BackColor;
}
```

---

*Using a custom property*:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Form1Reference = this;
form2.Show();
//form2.ShowDialog();
```

In `Form2`, using a property value:

```
public Form Form1Reference { get; set; }

private void btnSAVE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Form1Reference.BackColor = btnKAMU.BackColor;
}
```

---

*Setting a reference of **`Form1`** in `Form2` constructor*:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();
//form2.ShowDialog();
```

With a property value as before:

```
private Form Form1Reference { get; set; }

public Form2(Form Form1Instance)
{
    this.Form1Reference = Form1Instance;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnSAVE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Form1Reference.BackColor = btnKAMU.BackColor;
}
```

Or assign the `Form1` reference to a private Field:

```
private Form Form1Reference;

public Form2(Form Form1Instance)
{
    this.Form1Reference = Form1Instance;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnSAVE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Form1Reference.BackColor = btnKAMU.BackColor;
}
```

Depending on your context, it could be necessary to assing the chosen Color to a private Field and use its value to change `Form1.BackColor`

```
private Color Form1BackColor;

private void btnKAMU_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    colorDialog1.ShowDialog();
    btnKAMU.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
    this.Form1BackColor = btnKAMU.BackColor;
}
```

Change the previous code using this value if needed.

Comment: Thank you, Jimi. But now I have another problem. Actually it is like this; When I click on btnSAVE, we need to create a new Txt file and register a 5 button background color. And when the other form is loaded, its background should be Txt color. Like this.
Txt File:
FORM1 [RED] | FORM2 [BLUE] | FORM3 [BLACK]
and when form1 load, its background should be red, and if u can remember the colorDialog, when i choose a color and when i click btnSAVE, colors should be save in Txt file and when forms are loading backgrounds should be like in txt...

Comment: @DoganalpK  Well, that's a completly different question. You know how SO works: one question at the time. I can't answer it here. You have to post another question with this new requirement. You'll find answers quite quickly for this (as a hint, [start from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files?answertab=active#tab-top). If you get stuck, just ask SO, always showing what you have tried, doesn't matter if it's not working).