# Dynamic Enum creation at compile time in .net standard library

Tags: c#, enums, reflection.emit, .net-standard-2.0

I am working on a library project. I will distribute this library dll to some other projects for reference. My aim is to generate enum for each time , when ever the project(client project which referenced my dll) build.

I would like create Enum types based on values from api fetch at build time.
I am working on .net standard library (2.0) .
Requirement is to create a Enum at compile time based on a values, which i will fetch from api call.
I tried the following code

```
 // Get the current application domain for the current thread
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

        // Create a dynamic assembly in the current application domain,
        // and allow it to be executed and saved to disk.
        AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName("MyEnums");
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(name,
                                              AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        // Define a dynamic module in "MyEnums" assembly.
        // For a single-module assembly, the module has the same name as the assembly.
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(name.Name,
                                          name.Name + ".dll");

        // Define a public enumeration with the name "MyEnum" and an underlying type of Integer.
        EnumBuilder myEnum = moduleBuilder.DefineEnum("EnumeratedTypes.MyEnum",
                                 TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(int));
```

but "DefineDynamicAssembly" is not available.

Can anybody guide me to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the [documentation by MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.definedynamicassembly?view=netframework-4.8) the `DefineDynamicAssembly` method is only available starting from .NET Standard 2.

Comment: If you want to generate code at compile time this wont help you. `Reflection.Emit` generates code at runtime. Maybe just generate some c# lines as strings in a pre compilation step and add them to a template is a better way for you.

Comment: Have a look at [text templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates). These allow to generate C# code dynamically at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Program that writes a .cs file as you need it. In VisualStudio you can Run Commands before and after building a project. 
For creating Code at compile time, it's the easiest method. Depending on how complex it should be, a simple batch file should be enough but i don't think that api calls are that easy with a batch file.

I think you mean creating a enum at run time, because of the hassle with DefineDynamicAssembly.

Comment: hi can you give any sample code to do this, I am working on a library project. I will distribute this library dll to some other projects for reference. My aim is to generate enum for each time , when ever the project(client project which referenced my dll) build.Hope you get clear idea now.

Comment: @Noorul It's basically writing a Textfile. [For C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files) . Write a small C# Program, that creates an entire .cs file with the Enum and so on and add this Program to the pre build Events. 

What I didn't thought of what changing enums might cause for problems. But with this way you can also create a String that got defined at compile time and not during runtime.