# I have to add numbers from my list to a file

Tags: c#, list, file

This is my code, but everytime i try compiling it i keep getting this error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace nrinfile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> numbers= new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
            string[] folderLoc = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\folder\numbers.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                folderLoc[i] = Convert.ToString(numbers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < folderLoc.Length; i++) {...}`: there's *no guarantee* that `folderLoc` has *at least* `12` items

Comment: How many lines does the file E:\folder\numbers.txt have?

Comment: Please check how to write to files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files

Comment: There is nothing written in the folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: even if you fix `IndexOutOfRangeException` this code doesn't make sens ... it seems like you wana write those integers to the file but this is totally  wrong code

Answer (score 1):

There's *no guarantee* that `folderLoc` has *at least* `12` items

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {...}
```

You can put it like this (note `folderLoc.Length` instead of `12`):

```
        string[] folderLoc = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\folder\numbers.txt");

        // If you want at most 12 items to be changed put the condition as 
        //   i < Math.Max(12, folderLoc.Length)
        for (int i = 0; i < folderLoc.Length; i++)
        {
            folderLoc[i] = $"{i} {folderLoc[i]}"; //TODO: Apply the correct format here
        }
```

Or even (no explicit loops, but *Linq* query)

```
        using System.Linq;

        ...

        string[] folderLoc = File
          .ReadLines(@"E:\folder\numbers.txt")
          .Select((value, index) => $"{index} {value}")
          .ToArray();
```

If you want to change top `12` lines *only*, the `Select` should be

```
         ...
         .Select((value, index) => index < 12 ? $"{index} {value}" : value)
         ...
```

Finally, if you want just to write `0..11` numbers into a file

```
         File.WriteAllLines(@"E:\folder\numbers.txt", Enumerable.Range(0, 12));
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to write from your list of numbers to a file, you will need to use a System.IO method which *writes* to a file.

Something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string destFile = @"E:\folder\numbers.txt";

    List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(destFile)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count(); i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(numbers[i].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The `using` construct takes care of closing the file when the code has finished writing to it and disposing of any "unmanaged resources" that the StreamWriter used.

Instead of the `using` part and the code inside it, you could use a different method which takes an array of strings and writes that out as lines:

```
File.WriteAllLines(destFile, numbers.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());
```