# saving a class data as a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, io

I'm using binaryFormatter to encrypt data but i wanna save it without encryption.
so next time i just cast it .
this is the code that i'm using.

```
   //Creat a binaryFormatter
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    //Direction, Filename and Extention
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/enem.sav";

    //Creat the File (Blank)
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

    //Get the Data
    EnemData data = new EnemData();

    //Enter the Data and Encrypt it
    formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
    stream.Close();
```

Comment: BinaryFormatter does not encrypt your data, it just converts your object into a binary representation. Could you specify what you would like to achive? - because i don't really get what you want

Comment: i just don't want to convert my data to binary and im having hard time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JsonUtility.ToJson](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html) to convert your object's data into JSON format.

> ```
> public class PlayerState : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     public string playerName;
>     public int lives;
>     public float health;
>
>     public string SaveToString()
>     {
>         return JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
>     }
>
>     // Given:
>     // playerName = "Dr Charles"
>     // lives = 3
>     // health = 0.8f
>     // SaveToString returns:
>     // {"playerName":"Dr Charles","lives":3,"health":0.8}
> }
> ```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files) you can find how to read and write a string to and from a file.

> ```
> // Create a file to write to.
> string createText = "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine;
> File.WriteAllText(path, createText);
>
> // Open the file to read from.
> string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
> ```

To load the data simply use [JsonUtility.FromJson](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) or [JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html).

Example:

```
public class PlayerState : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string playerName;
    public int lives;
    public float health;
    public string path = "your file path";

    public string SaveToString()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, JsonUtility.ToJson(this));
    }

    public static PlayerState Load(string path)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerState>(File.ReadAllText(path));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you need. If you just want to serialize (turn your class into a binary representation and save to a file) and then get it back this should work for your:

```
    //Create a binaryFormatter
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    //Direction, Filename and Extention
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/enem.sav";

    //Creat the File (Blank)
    Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

    //Get the Data
    EnemData data = new EnemData { Id = 123, SomeBool = true, Name = "Enem" };

    //Enter the Data and Encrypt it
    formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
    stream.Close();


    //Restore it

    Stream stream2 = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    EnemData restoredClass = (EnemData)formatter.Deserialize(stream2);
    stream.Close();
```

But remember that you have to mark your class as serializable:

```
[Serializable]
public class EnemData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```