# Simplify script for my INT in every level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to store value of an INT **scoreValue** that is in scrip  "SCORE" in Unity game.

as for every level it will be different value, at the moment I'm doing separate function LEVEL1(), LEVEL2() etc. and store that value in **layerPrefs.SetInt("scoreLVL1", Score.scoreValue);** & **layerPrefs.SetInt("scoreLVL2", Score.scoreValue);** etc. etc.

but If I'm planning to have 100 levels, I would need to do 100 functions.

Is there simpler way to store all the values of each level in one function ?

I'm a beginner in Unity and at the moment can't get my head around it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string nextLevel = "Level02";
    public int levelToUnlock = 2;
    public sceneFade sceneFader;
    public PauseScript pauseresume;

    public void level1()
    {
        pauseresume.levelCompletedmenu();

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelReached") < levelToUnlock)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levelReached", levelToUnlock);
        }

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("scoreLVL1", Score.scoreValue);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    public void level2()
    {
        pauseresume.levelCompletedmenu();

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelReached") < levelToUnlock)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levelReached", levelToUnlock);
        }

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("scoreLVL2", Score.scoreValue);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the function level1(), use  function level(int levelNumber). It should help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what about

```c#
public void level(int level)
{
    pauseresume.levelCompletedmenu();

    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelReached") < levelToUnlock)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levelReached", levelToUnlock);
    }
    
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt($"scoreLVL{level}", Score.scoreValue);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

---

In general I would not recommend to use the `PlayerPrefs` for storing user progress. Rather (encrypt and) [write a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files) to [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)

Comment: I see you not recommend playerPrefs, but How would I call that stored value in other script?

int levelOneWonWithPoints = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level1"); 
int levelTwoWonWithPoints = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level2"); ??

Comment: what about e.g. a `Dictionary<int, int> levelToPoints` so you store one entry for each level and map it to the points ? E.g. reading `var secondLevelPoints = levelToPoints[2];` and writing `levelToPoints[2] = 500;`. Using e.g. [NewtonSoft .Net Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can directly (de)serialize from and to [`Dictionary`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm)