# Write in new text file after being created

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I want to write in the created text file from content in a textbox after it's been created in the app folder.

I'm getting an error saying that it can't write to it because another process is in use, how can I get around this?

I want the content from textbox3 to be written in the newly made file after it's been created. So the text file isn't there, it's making a text file from the user input on textBox2. I want the input from textBox3 to write in the new file right after it's been made.

> Error: `System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\app\x.txt' because it is being used by another process.'

Here's my code below:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}",
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));

    string filename = @"C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\app\" + textBox2.Text + ".txt";
    File.Create(filename);
    File.WriteAllText(filename, textBox3.Text);
}
```

Comment: I wonder from where comes the idea of calling `File.Create` and then `File.WriteAllText`? None of answers here (on SO) will do that, none of tutorials, nor [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to read from and write to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files)

Comment: You can get the desktop of the current user with `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`. Example: `string filename = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop, @"app\" + textBox2.Text + ".txt");`

Comment: I'm meaning that I'm wanting to write text from textBox3 into the newly created text file right after it's been made. I can't do this though because it's "being used by another process" and it's really annoying me.

Comment: As Jon Skeet tells you in his answer, drop the line `File.Create(filename);`, because `File.WriteAllText` does this internally already. `WriteAllText` creates the file, writes to it , and finally closes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File.Create` returns a `FileStream`, which will be open until it's disposed.

So you *could* just dispose of the returned value... but it would be simpler to remove the `File.Create` call entirely. If the file doesn't exist beforehand, it will be created by the `File.WriteAllText` call anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete noob at this, how could I use that to do the same task? Please don't judge me, I'm still learning :)
I want to create the file from textBox2 content and then write the text from textBox3 content to the app folder on the desktop.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting - simply remove the line of code `File.Create(filename);`. That's all you need to do. It will still write to the file on the next line.

Comment: I just tried it without that part and the text file wasn't created. I just removed it and nothing else, and it didn't make a .txt file.

Comment: You might have to hit the F5 key (for Refresh) on the Desktop to have it the new file displayed.

Comment: That code will *definitely* create a file.

Comment: Never mind guys, I forgot to change something in it. I accidentally chose the wrong path. Thanks for your help! :)