# How to create log file on sending email using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a log file after sending an email on button click by using the below code

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("emailid", "emialid");
mm.Subject = "GridView Email";
mm.Body = "GridView:<hr />" + sw.ToString();

mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "GridViewPDF.pdf"));
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
smtp.EnableSsl = true;

System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
NetworkCred.UserName = "emailid";
NetworkCred.Password = "password;

smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;

smtp.Port = 587;

smtp.Send(mm);

string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Email Send Successfully');</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files)

is a article write some text to text file. You could use for logging.

```
// Create a file to write to.
string createText = "Hello and Welcome" + Environment.NewLine;
File.WriteAllText(path, createText);

...

// Open the file to read from.
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
```