# How to save a variable that doesnt reset its value when reseting the windows service?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I want to save an access token inside a windows service and retrieve it evry time it is trying to make an api request.

How can i save the accesstoken safely inside the windows service so that it keeps its value after restart?

Comment: What options have you found so far and why don't they work for you?

Comment: I haven't found any options yet

Comment: I have read an answer to a similar question saying to save the data in filesystem or any other persistent storage but i dont know how to do that

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569904/easiest-way-to-read-from-and-write-to-files) is of any help.

Comment: this could help but i was wandering if there is a way to save the data inside the service not in an text file

Comment: I'd recommend looking into read/write to registry if it is only a single value, you want persisted.