# Copy an array of strings to new text file c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm having trouble with coppying an array of strings to a new text file,
When I create a new file,The file was created,but when I try
to copy the array to the new  text file,the file stays empty no matter what I tried.

I tried to use "using" to create the file,I have also tried to create a new text file without "using" and made sure not to forget to use "file.Close();" ,nothing seems to work.

any suggestions?

Jonathan.

this is my corrent code (the problem is located only after the "for" loop):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("FreeText.txt");
    string[] chars = fileContent.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for(int i =0;i<chars.Length;i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
            chars[i] = chars[i].ToUpper();
        else
            chars[i] = chars[i].ToLower();
    }

    using( FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Yonatan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Clab2\Clab2\bin\Debug\Test.txt",
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
    FileAccess.Write)) {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
        writer.WriteLine(chars);
        fs.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `strings` in the new files are in the `chars`, then should you not the `chars` line by line to your new file?

Comment: Yes sorry,I tried to copy some random text also.I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

use StreamWriter directly from file path

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       // Write single line to new file.
       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\log.txt", true))
       {
          writer.WriteLine("Important data line 1");
       }

       // Append line to the file.
       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\log.txt", true))
       {
           writer.WriteLine("Line 2");
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you need is in the answer here: [How to write data to a text file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153074/how-to-write-data-to-a-text-file-in-c)

I've included a solution anyhow:

```
   using( FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Test.txt",
                      FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                      FileAccess.Write))
   {
       StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
       byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(fileContent);
       fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
       fs.Close();
   }
```