# Build SQL command string

Tags: c#, sql

I want to build SQL query and save it to the text file. I need it to execute that query later. `DbCommand` can create valid SQL query, but how can I take the string representation of the query to save to file? Or maybe there is another way to build SQL and save it to string?

Comment: How about stored procedures?

Comment: Writing strings to a file has many options in .NET, StreamWriter, File.WriteAllLines, File.WriteAllText, etc. Can you clarify exactly what it is you're having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

while debugging, you can right click on the property and select "Add Watch".

Now in you watch window you see the Name & Value. Copy the Vlaue to clipboard and you can use it to your liking.

Comment: I operate with 1000+ insert-statements. So, it is not good solution

Comment: Then in code store the SQL query to the file, link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153074/how-do-i-write-data-to-a-text-file-in-c